# What time to meditate with daylight saving time?

Tags: meditation, chakras

We know that the best time to meditate is at 4 AM in the morning, but it gets tricky with daylight savings time.

Do we follow standard time zone or daylight savings time? Or do we need to meditate at 4 AM in whichever time we are following? (4AM in daylight savings or 4 AM at standard time, whichever time zone is currently followed)

I am also asking this because meditation before 4 AM is not recommended and has some side effects.

*Note: I feel like i wasn't able to ask my question properly. But I am not sure either how to word it properly. So if you have a recommendation please let me know.*

Comment: Time zone which you are currently following.Also 4am too is an rough estimate, Actually the time of Brahma Muhurta(if thats what you are referring to as time for meditation feel free to correct me here!) varies everyday and is defined as 2 muhurtas before sunrise and lasts for 1 muhurta period.(one muhurta=48 mins).Eg if sunrise is at 6 am then Brahma Muhurta lasts from 4:24 to 5:12 a.m. Hope this helps!

Comment: sunrise/sunset is the eternal clock not dst,zst,past,present etc.

Comment: @Rāmachandra, Thank you. That answered my question. Very informative.